# How to use the 'bit-blast' method to print the given formula in propositional logic form?

Tags: c++, z3, smt

I am creating a function that converts a bit-vector formula to Propositional logic form. 
A tactical called 'bit-blast' processes such bit-vector expressions to PL form.

I have  been trying to create a program that accepts bit-vector expressions and applies the bit-blast tactic on it. But as I am new to this topic I am not able to figure out how to print out the output after bit-blasting the expression.

```
#include<z3++.h>  
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace z3;

int main()
{   context c;
    tactic t = tactic(c, "bit-blast");
    expr x = c.bv_const("x", 16);
    expr y = c.bv_const("y", 16);
    expr z = c.bv_const("z", 16);
    goal g(c);
    g.add(z == x + y);
    std::cout<<g;


}
```

This is the code I have tried but it is not accepting the expression "z = x + y" 
But the process I am doing is correct? 
If not how am I supposed to printout the expression after applying bit-blast on it.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==`, not `=`. That is, `z == x + y`. And then, you of course have to apply the tactic:

```
#include<z3++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace z3;

int main()
{   context c;
    tactic t = tactic(c, "bit-blast");
    expr x = c.bv_const("x", 16);
    expr y = c.bv_const("y", 16);
    expr z = c.bv_const("z", 16);
    goal g(c);
    g.add(z == x + y);
    apply_result r = t(g);
    std::cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the bit-blasted goal; which is rather lengthy so I won't put it in here.

If you want to extract the actual expression, you need to do a bit more programming. (Incidentally: You really need to study the API https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3_09_09_8h_source.html first.)

Here's an example (I'm changing the original expression so the output is small enough to understand.):

```
#include<z3++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace z3;

int main()
{   context c;
    tactic t = tactic(c, "bit-blast");
    expr x = c.bv_const("x", 2);
    expr y = c.bv_const("y", 2);
    goal g(c);
    g.add(y == ~x);
    apply_result r = t(g);
    if(r.size() > 0)
    {
       expr res = r[0].as_expr();
       cout << res << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "tactic failed" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
$ c++ a.cpp -lz3; ./a.out
(and (not (= k!0 k!2)) (not (= k!1 k!3)))
```

And yes, you'll get `k!0` etc. as indexes which will be rather hard for you to relate back to your `x` and `y`; but that's inevitable: The bit-blaster will introduce new variables and the API has all the bits and pieces to reconstruct what you need: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3_09_09_8h_source.html

Comment: is there a way where I can generate a propositional logic form from bit-vector equation using bit-blast.?

Comment: can I save the apply results in an expression?