# How to convert c code to boolean expressions?

Tags: c, boolean-logic, converters

I would like to export a simple c code in equivalent boolean equations/expressions.
By example:

```
int main(void) {
   int i, a, b, c, r;

   a=1; b=2;
   c=a+b; %ADD operator
   c=c*b;

   c=c>>1; %RSHIFT operator

   r=10;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) { //... need to unwind the loop
      r=r+1; //r++;
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

Phase 1: step by step and unwinding loops

```
int main(void) {
   int I0, A0, B0, C0, R0;

   A0=1; B0=2;
   C0=A0 + B0; %ADD operator
   C1 = C0 * B0;

   C2 = C1 >> 1; %RSHIFT operator

   R0=10;
   //for(i=0;i<5;i++) { //... need to unwind the loop
   //   r=r+1; //r++;
   //}
   R1=R0+1;
   R2=R1+1;
   R3=R2+1;
   R4=R3+1;
   R5=R4+1;

   return 0; 
}
```

Phase 2: "binary equivalence"

```
%int I0, A0, B0, C0, R0; //suppose int=8bits in this case (simplification)

I = [i7 i6 i5 ... i0]; %binary register
A = [a7 a6 a5 ... a0];
B = [b7 b6 b5 ... b0];
C = [c7 c6 c5 ... c0];
R = [r7 r6 r5 ... r0];

%A0=1; B0=2;
A0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]; //a0=1 
B0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]; //b1=1

%C0=A0 + B0; %ADD operator  
C0 = binADD(A0,B0); %use only logic function (example: multiple full adder XOR(XOR(...),...))

%C1 = C0 * B0;
C1 = binMULTIPLY(C0, B0); %use only logic function

%C2 = C1 >> 1; %RSHIFT operator
=> C2 = SHIFTR(C1,1);
C2_0 = C1_1;
C2_1 = C1_2;
C2_2 = C1_3;
C2_3 = C1_4;
C2_4 = C1_5;
C2_5 = C1_6;
C2_6 = C1_7;
C2_7 = 0;

%R0=10;
%R1=R0+1;
%R2=R1+1;
%R3=R2+1;
%R4=R3+1;
%R5=R4+1;

...
```

At the end, I would like to get an expression for one of my variable.

By example for C:
C = f(A,B) = f(a7,a6,...a0,b7,b6,...b0)

Suppose a or b could be a value between 0 and 255 (a=k1; b=k2;)

I saw a lot of software: CMBC, NuSMV, etc. But I can't find how to just export the equivalent boolean expressions (example in CNF - binary form).

Note: my objective is to convert those expressions in logic circuit.

Comment: `boolean, CNF` ok, some formulas with true/false values and logical operators... `b=2` What's a "2"?

Comment: I would like b to be "expressed" in binary. So, b=(10)_2 = (b1,b0) = (1,0) = (b1 2^1 + b0). Maybe in 8 or 16-digits format. Do you a software capable of doing that? Those kind of transformations must be in FPGA softwares, I think...

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to achieve first. A boolean formula in CNF will have some inputs and one true/false output. Your program has... no inputs and always returns zero. Nope, not getting it. Maybe you should do the sample conversion by hand and show what you wanted to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bit-blasting tactics of SMT solvers to achieve some of what you're trying to do. Note that the result will neither be easy to read, nor easy to dissect by anything but further programs. See this question/answer for pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819837/936310